Adding Panels to Panel inside Scroll Pane in Java not Working
I'm working on this scheduler project. I already got the data for the gantt chart (process, clock tick it executed, and it's remaining burst time). However, I can't seem to make the processBlock be displayed at the blockObjectsPanel (Panel) within a blockObjectsPane (Scroll Pane).
I tried outputting the components of the Panel, and true enough there are processBlock panels added. But it can't be displayed. Additionally, whenever I try to print that block, it outputs an invalid field.
Here's the output in the terminal. The schedulerComponents.processBlock is invalid
===============================
id: ID: -1
bt: Burst: 0
Before adding block: 0
After adding block: 1
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@74d39a2a,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 2
bt: Burst: 7
Before adding block: 1
After adding block: 2
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@2d1e5004,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 4
bt: Burst: 7
Before adding block: 2
After adding block: 3
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@6706ee81,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 10
bt: Burst: 7
Before adding block: 3
After adding block: 4
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@612b0999,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 8
bt: Burst: 2
Before adding block: 4
After adding block: 5
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@3c2dd6fd,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 9
bt: Burst: 5
Before adding block: 5
After adding block: 6
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@3944661a,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 7
bt: Burst: 5
Before adding block: 6
After adding block: 7
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@40ac6329,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 1
bt: Burst: 6
Before adding block: 7
After adding block: 8
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@65a86d03,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 3
bt: Burst: 7
Before adding block: 8
After adding block: 9
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@3cc5327d,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 6
bt: Burst: 7
Before adding block: 9
After adding block: 10
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@5c5ff31c,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 5
bt: Burst: 6
Before adding block: 10
After adding block: 11
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@68321c2c,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 2
bt: Burst: 1
Before adding block: 11
After adding block: 12
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@4049a239,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 4
bt: Burst: 0
Before adding block: 12
After adding block: 13
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@2c6438ce,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 10
bt: Burst: 1
Before adding block: 13
After adding block: 14
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@4874936c,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================
id: ID: 3
bt: Burst: 1
Before adding block: 14
After adding block: 15
schedulerComponents.processBlock[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.GroupLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.LineBorder@67da96cb,flags=9,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=70,height=70]]
===============================

Here's the code for the ganttChart.java
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JPanel.java to edit this template
 */
package schedulerComponents;

import com.mycompany.processFinal.MFQS.GanttChartEntry;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

/**
 *
 * @author LENOVO
 */
public class ganttChart extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form ganttChart
     */
    public ganttChart() {
        initComponents();
//      processBlock block = new processBlock();
//      blockObjectsPanel.add(block);
//      System.out.println("Hello hays");
////        blockObjectsPanel.revalidate();
////        blockObjectsPanel.repaint();
//          
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the
     * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

                ganttChartLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
                initPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
                blockObjectsPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
                blockObjectsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

                ganttChartLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
                ganttChartLabel.setText("Gantt Chart");

                blockObjectsPane.setToolTipText("");
                blockObjectsPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                blockObjectsPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
                blockObjectsPane.setDoubleBuffered(true);
                blockObjectsPane.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 3000));
                blockObjectsPane.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 300));
                blockObjectsPane.setViewportView(null);

                blockObjectsPanel.setAutoscrolls(true);
                blockObjectsPanel.setDoubleBuffered(false);
                blockObjectsPanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1500, 300));
                blockObjectsPanel.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(blockObjectsPanel, javax.swing.BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
                blockObjectsPane.setViewportView(blockObjectsPanel);

                javax.swing.GroupLayout initPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(initPanel);
                initPanel.setLayout(initPanelLayout);
                initPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                        initPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(blockObjectsPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                );
                initPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                        initPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(blockObjectsPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 300, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                );

                blockObjectsPane.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(this);

                javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
                this.setLayout(layout);
                layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(ganttChartLabel)
                                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                        .addComponent(initPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addContainerGap())
                );
                layout.setVerticalGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(ganttChartLabel)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(initPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addContainerGap())
                );
        }// </editor-fold>                        
    public void displayGanttChart (List<GanttChartEntry> ganttChartEntries){
        blockObjectsPanel.removeAll();
        for(GanttChartEntry entry: ganttChartEntries){
            processBlock block = new processBlock();
            block.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70)); // Set the preferred size as needed

            blockObjectsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(blockObjectsPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

            block.setProcessID(entry.getProcessId());
            block.setBurstTime(entry.getEndTime() - entry.getStartTime());
            System.out.println("===============================");
            System.out.println("id: "+block.getProcessId());
            System.out.println("bt: "+block.getBurstTimeLabel());
            
            System.out.println("Before adding block: " + blockObjectsPanel.getComponentCount());
            blockObjectsPanel.add(block);
            System.out.println("After adding block: " + blockObjectsPanel.getComponentCount());
            
            blockObjectsPanel.setVisible(true);
            blockObjectsPanel.revalidate();
            blockObjectsPanel.repaint();
            System.out.println(blockObjectsPanel.getComponent(blockObjectsPanel.getComponentCount()-1));
        }
        blockObjectsPanel.revalidate();
        blockObjectsPanel.repaint();
        blockObjectsPane.revalidate();
        blockObjectsPane.repaint();
    }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane blockObjectsPane;
        public javax.swing.JPanel blockObjectsPanel;
        private javax.swing.JLabel ganttChartLabel;
        private javax.swing.JPanel initPanel;
        // End of variables declaration                   
}



I assume that you think that someone will be able to tell you how to fix your code just by looking at it. I very much doubt that will happen. Also, your code uses GroupLayout which leads me to believe that you are using a GUI builder. I recommend not using a GUI builder if you are not experienced in using Swing. I suggest that you read [ask] and then [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

Although the answer contains good advice, it may not resolve your problem since you did not post a [mcve]. It is not clear (at least to me) if method displayGanttChart is called multiple times, for example as a result of a user action such as pressing a button, or once only - when you initialize your application GUI.

You set the layout manager inside the loop for each iteration. It should be set once before adding any components to ensure it doesn't get reset. Move the BoxLayout configuration outside of the loop:
blockObjectsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(blockObjectsPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

You call revalidate and repaint after each addition, which is good. However, you might want to verify that all these calls occur outside the loop after all components have been added. This ensures that the final layout updates correctly after all components are added:
for(GanttChartEntry entry: ganttChartEntries){
}

blockObjectsPanel.setVisible(true);
blockObjectsPanel.revalidate();
blockObjectsPanel.repaint();
blockObjectsPane.revalidate();
blockObjectsPane.repaint();

try temporarily replacing the BoxLayout with a simpler layout manager like FlowLayout to see if it changes the behavior. This can help identify if the issue is layout-related.
public void displayGanttChart(List<GanttChartEntry> ganttChartEntries) {
    blockObjectsPanel.removeAll();
    blockObjectsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(blockObjectsPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); // Move outside the loop

    for (GanttChartEntry entry : ganttChartEntries) {
        processBlock block = new processBlock();
        block.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70)); // Set the preferred size as needed
        block.setProcessID(entry.getProcessId());
        block.setBurstTime(entry.getEndTime() - entry.getStartTime());

        System.out.println("===============================");
        System.out.println("id: " + block.getProcessId());
        System.out.println("bt: " + block.getBurstTimeLabel());

        System.out.println("Before adding block: " + blockObjectsPanel.getComponentCount());
        blockObjectsPanel.add(block);
        System.out.println("After adding block: " + blockObjectsPanel.getComponentCount());
    }

    blockObjectsPanel.setVisible(true);
    blockObjectsPanel.revalidate();
    blockObjectsPanel.repaint();
    blockObjectsPane.revalidate();
    blockObjectsPane.repaint();
}

